# Want to check from chrome extension if user is loggedIn to the site?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-storage

I have developed a chrome extension using angular for a website (developed in PHP) and it is running . Extension has a button and I want to enable/disable this button based the condition that if user is logged in or not

Comment: It depends on how the state of the user is saved. To check a cookie see `chrome.cookies` API. To check localStorage of the site, use a `content script`.

Comment: Is that site has something to double check that the user logged in or not? Like when user access to `/home/` then the site will redirect to `/login/` if not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the state of your current user in `localStorage` (make sure to *set* and *remove* the current user upon login/logout. Assuming you are using `JWT` or standard it should be fairly easy.

On your background/content script use:

```
        chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
          console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
        });

        chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
          console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
        });
```